# Minimum length routing path - Dynamic Programing

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

There are 2*N pins on a line, N of them are input pins, N of them are output pins. Every input pin must be connected to a single output pin and vice-versa, like in this image:

[image]

The connection lines can be made only vertically and horizontally in the upper half plane and the connection lines can no overlap.

The question is what is the minimum length of all lines that can be achieved when connecting all pins.

In the example above, the length is 31.

A greedy approach using a stack, similar to matching parenthesis problem is not the optimal solution.

Comment: Homework? Interview question?

Comment: Are the input-pins and output-pins at fixed locations ? Else the answer will likely be `3*N`.

Comment: in and out pins are at fixed locations.

Comment: Can pins connect in either direction? Meaning could a `1` connect with a `0` to its left side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the outermost line between 1 and 8, then it splits the pins into two groups. One between 2 and 7, and the other between 9 and 10.

Each of these groups has a constraint on the maximum line height it can have without extending past the outer line. 2 for the first, and some default like 5 for the second.

This gives a function `lineLength(leftPin, rightPin, maxHeight)` that can get its value by finding a height `h` and pin `i` so that `h <= maxHeight` and `pin[i]` is between `leftPin+1` and `rightPin` and the opposite type of `pin[leftPin]`.

Then the line length would be `rightPin-leftPin+2*h + lineLength(leftPin+1, i-1, h-1) + lineLength(i+1, rightPin-1, 5)`

There are `O(n^3)` possible values for this function and calculating each value, with memoization, would require `O(n^2)` time because of the iterations of `h` and `i`. So the total time is `O(n^5)`.

It should be possible to improve this with a binary search on the maximum height.

Answer (score 0):

Divide and conquer can get this down to n^2.

In general, the first pin must be paired with something - and the only options for its pairing are when the string of pins have an even number of input and output bits. So in the example #1 can pair with #8 or #10.

For each of these pairings, you add the cost of that wire to the sub-problem inside the wire, and the subproblem outside the wire.

For example: if we're pairing 1 and 8, then

`cost = recursiveCost (2,7) + recursivecost(9,end) + wireCost(1,8)`

You'll also need to track the maximum recursive depth of the inside function call, because you'll need that to calculate wireCost(a,b).

Comment: How would you track height in your recursion? In the OP's example (assuming connections can go in either direction), connecting 3 with 6 would imply different heights for earlier function calls, a variable which seems dependent on the nesting configuration.

Comment: The recursive method can return its depth and its cost in a wrapper object - like a struct or some class - so that the caller can also calculate his cost and add one to the depth, etc